# RStudio: Create list for Clickstream Analysis

Tags: r, list

I try to create a list with one row per session without NA's and with one element per click to apply clickstream analysis (markov chain). Let's pretend we have the following matrix:

```
> sessions = rbind(c(1:3,NA,NA), c(1:2,NA,NA,NA), c(1:5))
> sessions
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3   NA   NA
[2,]    1    2   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

My goal is to create out of the matrix "sessions" **a list** **without NA's** which looks like this:

```
$Session1
[1] "1" "2" "3"

$Session2
[1] "1" "2"

$Session3
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
```

Since I am a novice in R, I have no clue how to manage this. Do you have any ideas? I would be very glad for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split`

```
res <- lapply(split(sessions, seq(nrow(sessions))), 
               function(x) as.numeric(na.omit(x)))
res
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3

#$`2`
#[1] 1 2

#$`3`
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Or `asplit` -

```
res <- lapply(asplit(sessions, 1), function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
```

To name the list you can use -

```
names(res) <- paste0('session', seq_along(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `apply` here (tested on `R 4.1.0`)

```
apply(sessions, 1, \(x) x[complete.cases(x)])
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try `na.omit`

```
> apply(sessions, 1, na.omit)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 4 5
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"

[[2]]
[1] 1 2
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 3 4 5
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: It would be nice to have an option to return with attr or not.  The current function always return with attr when the NA are present `if (any(omit > 0L)) {...;attr(omit, "class") <- "omit"
        attr(object, "na.action") <- omit`

Comment: @akrun Yes, exactly, I agree!